# Glide not downloading image

Tags: java, android

I have array of object with some parameters.

One of the parameters is imageUrl.

I'm trying to download them with Glide library, and all of them is downloaded and shown on the RecyclerView.

But , one of them no appear.

Here is the image url that not shown.

```
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068646/mediaviewer/rm746868224
```

When I'm opening this url with my browser, the image appear.

Here is my code to show the all images.

```
Glide.with(getContext())
                .load(mMoviesResponse.getImage())
                .into(mIVMovieImage);
```

BTW,
others image has urls like this one and they are working good:

```
https://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/2.jpg
```

Comment: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068646/mediaviewer/rm746868224 is not an image URL. An HTML that contains an Image.

Answer (score 0):

Because ***url*** you provided is not ***image***'s ***url***. It is a web page(You see there is no extension like ***jpg***, ***png*** etc. at the end of your ***url***). Use this ***url*** instead: https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BM2MyNjYxNmUtYTAwNi00MTYxLWJmNWYtYzZlODY3ZTk3OTFlXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzkwMjQ5NzM@._V1_SY1000_CR0,0,704,1000_AL_.jpg

I got it via `Right mouse click on image > copy image address`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i can't use custom link, because that's what I receive from api.

Any ideas how to solve?

Comment: what api ? How can api deliver that url ?

Comment: I'm doing a chore to get a new job, and that's what they sent me with api.
I think they did it on purpose to see how I solved it ... or they themselves don't know that this link is not a picture.

Comment: Sorry but I dont think it is possible to show that page as an image. It is a problem of API, not your code.

Comment: So tell them that this url is a web page and cant be viewed